# Get user count that made a specific number of purchases in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Each user in my shop can make multiple purchases and information about such purchase is being stored inside ElasticSearch 6.5.

I would like to count how many users made a specific number of purchases in my shop - **one or three**. We would base our search on a documents called `user_purchases` looking like this:

```
{
    "user_id" : 1,
    "total_value" : 111.56,
    "total_products" : 2
}
```

If we were to make this using SQL we would do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM users u WHERE u.id IN (SELECT up.user_id FROM user_purchases up WHERE COUNT(up.id) = 1 GROUP BY up.user_id);

SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM users u WHERE u.id IN (SELECT up.user_id FROM user_purchases up WHERE COUNT(up.id) = 3 GROUP BY up.user_id);
```

I have been using ElasticSearch for some time now but this case is giving me a serious headache. I have tried to find some similar case examples but google is not cooperating very well and ES documentation does not have too many examples to figure it out.

It seems it would be best to make three separate queries for each - **one or three** - case and maybe use painless + ctx scripting but I just don't know where to start looking. I worked with it a little doing less complicated 'if contains this then do that` actions but this here will take me a very long time to figure out.

If anyone could help out and give an example of a query using search or multisearch API (or any other that would work) I would be very greatful!

Comment: I'm not sure you can capture the 0 condition even in SQL `WHERE COUNT(up.id) = 0 GROUP BY up.user_id`, i.e. how can you count something that is not there? You'd have to supply the list of all user_ids in a WHERE clause in order to achieve that

Comment: You are right, thank you, I have made changes and removed 'no-purchases' option. I have dealt with it differently - I have also `users` documents where I have added a bool field `has_made_purchases` and I am checking for `false` values there. However the remainder of cases remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have managed to accomplish what I need. Let's say we have an index called `visitor_carts` with documents like that:

```
{
    "visitor_id" : 1,
    "total_value" : 111,
    "total_products" : 2
}

{
    "visitor_id" : 1,
    "total_value" : 199.99,
    "total_products" : 1
}

{
    "visitor_id" : 1,
    "total_value" : 890.56,
    "total_products" : 2
}

{
    "visitor_id" : 2,
    "total_value" : 223.56,
    "total_products" : 2
}

{
    "visitor_id" : 3,
    "total_value" : 4.56,
    "total_products" : 2
}
```

There is a solution - it is called [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). With that you can build pretty much anything you want, the downside is that you have to familiarize yourself with [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html) scripting. The documentation in that regard is quite hard to understand, on top of that it seems specific versions are not very well maintained as what is in painless documentation does not work with my version of ElasticSearch 6.5 (even though it should according to said documentation). So a word of warning - if it does not work keep looking for more examples. I have found [usage examples here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scripted-metric-aggregation-usage.html) very useful. Anyways here is the working solution:

```
POST visitor_carts/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "purchases": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script" : "state['visitorPurchases'] = [:]",
        "map_script" : "if (state['visitorPurchases'].containsKey(doc['visitor_id'].value)) {state['visitorPurchases'][doc['visitor_id'].value]++} else {state['visitorPurchases'][doc['visitor_id'].value] = 1}",
        "combine_script": "def combine = [:]; for (visitor in state['visitorPurchases'].entrySet()) {if (combine.containsKey(visitor.getValue().toString())) {combine[visitor.getValue().toString()]++} else {combine[visitor.getValue().toString()] = 1}} return combine",
        "reduce_script": "def reduce = [:]; for (shard in states) { for (count in shard.entrySet()) {if (reduce.containsKey(count.getKey())) {reduce[count.getKey()] += count.getValue()} else {reduce[count.getKey()] = count.getValue()}}} return reduce"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `map_script` it looks through all the documents matched by the query and counts occurences of every `visitor_id`. Then in `combine_script` it takes what `map_script` prepared earlier and groups the result by occurence count. As `combine_script` works per shard we need to have the `reduce_script` bring together all results sets from every shard and return it like:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "purchases" : {
      "value" : {
        "1" : 2,
        "3" : 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to the [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) documentation to find out what each of the script types do and then follow the [usage examples here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scripted-metric-aggregation-usage.html) to construct what you need.

I am too fresh with ElasticSearch to be able to tell how efficient that solution is. It works well with a few thousands of documents I have tested it against but I have no idea how it will behave with millions/billions of records. If anyone cares to test this - be my guest :)

Comment: That's a good example of using `scripted_metric`, I was going to suggest an updated answer, but that's great if you found out yourself!

Comment: Im am only wondering which solution would be more efficient and/or less memory consuming, maybe will check out later once I deliver the project I am sitting on.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `user_id` field, you're going to get a list of buckets of the users who've made the most purchases down to the ones who've made only a single purchase. You can then filter out all the buckets that you don't want using a [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1_3": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "nb_purchases": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.nb_purchases == 1 || params.nb_purchases == 3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is close, but I had to instead of doing `"terms": "user_id"` do `"terms": {"field":"user_id"}` plus the sub aggs need to be nested under "users" main aggs, not be put next to it in a tree.
Also I am looking on to how to make it return bucket count instead of getting "key" and "doc_count" info about every bucket. It has to work with hundreds of thousands of users so returning a huuuge array and counting it later is not the best solution.

Comment: Doh, typing from memory sometimes bites me, sorry about that typo. it's fixed now.

Comment: Well, I have managed to find a solution and posted it as an answer. But your answer might be useful for somebody else anyway is somebody for example is looking for the document counts and not the bucket counts.

Comment: I have made a follow-up question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146841/count-buckets-returned-by-sub-aggregation/56164387?noredirect=1#comment98974371_56164387 where @Kamal managed to get a number of buckets stats, so your answer combined with the other question should work too.