# Count buckets returned by sub aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to count the number of buckets from a result set returned by [pipe aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-pipeline.html). Problem is that my query that is using [script selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) here:

```json
POST visitor_carts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "visitors": {
      "terms": {"field" : "visitor_id"},
      "aggs": {
        "one_purchase": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "nb_purchases": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.nb_purchases == 3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns something like that:

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "visitors" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "3",
          "doc_count" : 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Under the `buckets` key I can see a list of visitors that meet my condition (every visitor identified by `visitor_id` must have exactly three documents in the `visitor_carts` index) but that is not very helpful because it should handle instead hundreds of thousands of visitors. I am using PHP to handle the results, theoretically it could count the result set but with a large volume of visitors it feels like not the best idea. Is there a way to just output the count of valid buckets next to `doc_count_error_upper_bound` and `sum_other_doc_count`? It is a little odd that there is no `bucket_count` included in the aggregation stats as it seems to be quite useful.

Or maybe this can be done in a different way? This question is a follow-up for this one: [Get user count that made a specific number of purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112844/get-user-count-that-made-a-specific-number-of-purchases-in-elasticsearch/56113760?noredirect=1#comment98893453_56113760)

Here is my `visitor_carts` mapping:

```json
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "created_dt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "order_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "visitor_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [Stats Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html) to get the count of buckets.

Below is how your query would be.

### Aggregation Query:

```json
POST visitor_carts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "visitors": {
      "terms": {
        "field" : "visitor_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "one_purchase": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "nb_purchases": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.nb_purchases == 3"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mybucketcount":{
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path":"visitors._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Aggregation Result:

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "visitors": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "3",
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    "mybucketcount": {
      "count": 2,              <---- This is the count you are looking for
      "min": 3,
      "max": 3,
      "avg": 3,
      "sum": 6
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need document count. I need bucket count, so in your result is should be number 2. Or in other words count of the distinct keys under the `buckets` key.

Comment: Oops!! I've updated my answer with what you are looking for. Please check and let me know if that is what you are looking for.