# Bucket count on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to extract users with statistics on wearable device usage. The loyal users are the ones who have used the wearable device for more than 20 days in the last 30 day and their average usage of the wearable device is greater than 4 hours per day.
So, in short, a loyal user = (minimum 20 days use + avg use per day > 4 hrs)

In Elasticsearch the usage documents are indexed according to the dates and usage hours.

```
{
id:"AL-2930",
"usage_duration":4.5,
"sessionDate":"2020-05-01" 
},
{
id:"AL-2930",
"usage_duration":5.5,
"sessionDate":"2020-05-02" 
},
{
id:"AL-2931",
"usage_duration":3.5,
"sessionDate":"2020-05-01" 
},
{
id:"AL-2931",
"usage_duration":3.0,
"sessionDate":"2020-05-02" 
},
```

The query I'm trying to run gives the results correctly.

```
{

  "aggs": {
    "users": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "min_doc_count": 20,
        "order" : { "_key" : "asc" }
      },
   
      "aggs": {
        "avg_usage": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "usage_duration"
          }
           
        },
        "usage_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "avgUsage": "avg_usage"
            },
            "script": "params.avgUsage > 4.0"
          }
        
        }
        
      }
    }

  }


}
```

The results I get is like this:

```
{
    "took": 15,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2139,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "patients": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 1926,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A100CR",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 4.5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A102XF",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 5.5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A103ZU",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 5.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A104IA",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 6.5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A104ZL",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 4.5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A106BT",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 5.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "BG-P-A110VY",
                    "doc_count": 24,
                    "avg_usage": {
                        "value": 5.5
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

What I really need is the query to return the total number of buckets in the buckets found. I tried answer from a similar question ([Count buckets returned by sub aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146841/count-buckets-returned-by-sub-aggregation)) but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would the below help:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "min_doc_count": 20,
        "order" : { "_key" : "asc" },
        "size": 100,                       <----- Added this
        "show_term_doc_count_error": true  <----- Added this 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_usage": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "usage_duration"
          }
        },
        "usage_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "avgUsage": "avg_usage"
            },
            "script": "params.avgUsage > 4.0"
          }
        },
        "bucket_count":{
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "return params.count"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mybucketcount":{
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path":"users._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the above query by replacing the `"script": "params.avgUsage > 4.0"` to `"script": "params.avgUsage > 3.0"` and made `min_doc_count as 2` for the documents set you've mentioned in question and I see the below response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "AL-2930",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "avg_usage" : {
            "value" : 5.0
          },
          "bucket_count" : {
            "value" : 2.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "AL-2931",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "avg_usage" : {
            "value" : 3.25
          },
          "bucket_count" : {
            "value" : 2.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "mybucketcount" : {
      "count" : 2,             <---- Note this.
      "min" : 2.0,
      "max" : 2.0,
      "avg" : 2.0,
      "sum" : 4.0
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that you would need the total number of buckets returned by [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) i.e. for `users` and I've simply added the [Stats Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) to what you have.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: It only shows 7 results when I try the bucket count over the elastic index. The actual loyal user count that I have in the index is around 82.  I have validated the count from an excel export file of the index with manual counting.

Comment: @Dony could you share your mapping. I'm wondering why is it that you only see 7 buckets. Coz it should work unless there is some issue with any nodes. Could you also check the status of your cluster and confirm that all your nodes/shards are good.

Comment: Also note this in your response `"sum_other_doc_count": 1926`. Could you please try the answer I've updated once more as I've added some more parameters. Let me know what do you observe. Also please do verify by taking two or three sample terms which you think should be coming up as answer but did not show up in if you do a sample term query for that particular term. Note that if the values are case sensitive, it would be treated differently for e.g. `BG-P-A104IA` and `Bg-P-A104IA` are two separate terms. Please do review that as well.

Comment: Yes, the updated answer returns the correct count of 82 users. Thank You